# How can I make my spaceship move forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a "Astroids" kind of game, and just added turning around by the left and the right keys on my keyboard:

```
if( Input.GetKey("left"))
{
    GameObject.Find("ship").transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 1);
}

if (Input.GetKey("right"))
{
    GameObject.Find("ship").transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -1);
}
```

But in order to move forward I have to take into account the current rotation of the ship. How do I do that?

```
if (Input.GetKey("up"))
{
    // move forward
}
```

Do I have to calculate cosine and sine, and how do I apply them?

Comment: try this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html

Comment: Don't the vectors just add up by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all cache your `ship` variable

```
float speed = 10f;
Transform ship = GameObject.Find("ship").transform;

if( Input.GetKey("left"))
{
    ship.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 1);
}

if (Input.GetKey("right"))
{
    ship.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -1);
}
if (Input.GetKey("up"))
{
    // move forward
    ship.Translate(ship.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime)
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to state that its a 2D game. When I press UP Z value changes which in turn does nothing. Could change it to UP, but its messed up movement

Answer (score 0):

I used the rigidbody addforce function which worked really well. There's a 2d version of it as well. Check the docs here

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

very useful :)